# How to simulate a broken application/octet-stream using java

Tags: java, html, download

I have a java web application which will produce an http page with a link to download a file.
When the link is clicked, it will go to an API and the API will send a `HttpResponse response` and the response contentType is

```
resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

The browser then will save the file to the Operating System's Downloads directory.

Now if the file is missing or corrupted how do we programmatically and produce a download fail to the browser? Is there some kind of header that I should use?

Please note that I have the opportunity to know before the stream start if the file is missing, but I have to work within an html hyperlink basis.

Comment: Can you post code so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options to show errors, for example:

1. just give some HTTP error code
2. redirect the user to some (existing) error page (and do not set the contentType)

I would prefer the second one.

I think you are using `HttpServletResponse` and not `HttpResponse` (I can be wrong). If so, you can redirect the user with `sendRedirect()` method.

Comment: Thank you, also worth mentioning using `resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Some error message");`

Answer (score 1):

If the file is missing, this should be communicated to the client using a HTTP status 404 (not found).

```
resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
```